# How to write conditional statement in wordpress function.php

Tags: wordpress, function, conditional-statements, infinite-scroll

I am using wordpress and I am trying to add the infinite scroll function only on my home, archives and categories pages.

But I am quite a newbie at PHP, I thought I could write it that way in my **functions.php**

```
if ( is_home() || is_archive() || is_category()  ) {
function quailstudio_infinite_scroll_init() {
add_theme_support( 'infinite-scroll', array(
        'type'           => 'scroll',
        'container'      => 'content',
        'wrapper'        => false,
        'render'         => 'render', 
        'posts_per_page' => 12,
    ) ); } add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'quailstudio_infinite_scroll_init' ); }
```

But it is clearly not the right way to do it.

What would be the proper way to write that?

Comment: add your `if` statement into function `quailstudio_infinite_scroll_init`

Answer (score 0):

Close, but when you put the function definition **inside** the conditional statement, it means that your function might not be defined, which is required for the `add_action()` method call you have following it (which is also outside the conditional).

You should instead put the conditional statement **inside** the function, like so:

```
function quailstudio_infinite_scroll_init() {
    if ( is_home() || is_archive() || is_category()  ) {
        add_theme_support( 'infinite-scroll', array(
            'type'           => 'scroll',
            'container'      => 'content',
            'wrapper'        => false,
            'render'         => 'render', 
            'posts_per_page' => 12,
        ) ); 
    } 
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'quailstudio_infinite_scroll_init' );
```

Comment: thanks but that doesn't seem to work, I just tried it (>_<)

Comment: This is the correct way to do this. If you need it on the homepage perhaps try adding `is_front_page()` to the conditional. So like `if( is_home() || is_front_page() ...`

Comment: @AmauryLemal What do you mean by "doesn't seem to work"? Nobody can help you further unless you provide more details about what actual issues you're encountering.